# Implementing exponential General Linear Model in Stan/RStan

Tags: r, statistics, regression, stan, rstan

I have the following model:

[image]

I wish to learn how to implement this model.

**Research and Attempt**

I’ve had a look at the following Poisson GLM as an example:

[image]

````
```{stan output.var="PoissonGLMQR"}
  data{
    int<lower=1> n;     // number of observations
    int<lower=1> p;     // number of predictors
    matrix[n, p] x;     // design matrix
    int<lower=0> y[n];  // responses
  }
  
  transformed data{
    matrix [n, p] Q_ast;
    matrix [p, p] R_ast;
    matrix [p, p] R_ast_inverse;
    Q_ast = qr_Q(x)[,1:p] * sqrt(n - 1.0);
    R_ast = qr_R(x)[1:p,] / sqrt(n - 1.0);
    R_ast_inverse = inverse(R_ast);
  }
  
  parameters{
    vector[p] theta;  // regression coefficients for predictors
  }
  
  transformed parameters{
    vector[p] beta;
    vector[n] mu;
    mu = exp(Q_ast*theta);
    beta = R_ast_inverse * theta;
  }
  
  model{
     y  ~ poisson(mu);
  }
```
````

I understand that this example has used QR reparameterization (see section 9.2 of the Stan reference manual). However, since I’m new to Stan, I’m finding this quite intimidating, and I’m unsure of how to implement the exponential GLM in the same way. Does one even need to use the QR reparameterization for the exponential case?

Anyway, my naive attempt at the exponential GLM is the following adaptation of the Poisson GLM code:

````
```{stan output.var="ExponentialGLM"}
  data{
    int<lower=1> n;     // number of observations
    int<lower=1> p;     // number of predictors
    matrix[n, p] x;     // design matrix
    real<lower=0> y[n];  // responses
  }
  
  transformed data{
    matrix [n, p] Q_ast;
    matrix [p, p] R_ast;
    matrix [p, p] R_ast_inverse;
    Q_ast = qr_Q(x)[,1:p] * sqrt(n - 1.0);
    R_ast = qr_R(x)[1:p,] / sqrt(n - 1.0);
    R_ast_inverse = inverse(R_ast);
  }
  
  parameters{
    vector[p] theta;  // regression coefficients for predictors
  }
  
  transformed parameters{
    vector[p] beta;
    vector[n] mu;
    mu = exp(Q_ast*theta);
    beta = (R_ast_inverse * theta);
  }
  
  model{
     y  ~ exponential(mu);
  }
```
````

But, I’m totally unsure if this is even the right way to go about coding such a model in Stan. All I did was simply try to adapt the Poisson GLM example to the aforementioned exponential GLM.

I am seeking a demonstration of the exponential GLM and clarifications regarding my misunderstandings above.

**Sample Data**

```
    conc  time
 1   6.1   0.8
 2   4.2   3.5
 3   0.5  12.4
 4   8.8   1.1
 5   1.5   8.9
 6   9.2   2.4
 7   8.5   0.1
 8   8.7   0.4
 9   6.7   3.5
10   6.5   8.3
11   6.3   2.6
12   6.7   1.5
13   0.2  16.6
14   8.7   0.1
15   7.5   1.3
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? I'm also confused about the general model. Are you talking about a Poisson model or an Exponential (i.e. Gamma) model? Those are two different things. The `glm` equivalents are `glm(..., family = poisson)` and `glm(..., family = Gamma)`. In a first step you should compare the output of your Stan model with that from `glm`. Do point estimates agree?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks for the response. I'm talking about an Exponential model. The Poisson model that I posted was a totally separate example that I was trying to use in order to determine how to do the Exponential model. I have edited my post with some sample data. If anything else is unclear, please don't hesitate to ask. I'm totally unsure of how to implement this model, so help is greatly appreciated.Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

1. We start by reading in the sample data.

   ```
   df <- read.table(text =
       "    conc  time
    1   6.1   0.8
    2   4.2   3.5
    3   0.5  12.4
    4   8.8   1.1
    5   1.5   8.9
    6   9.2   2.4
    7   8.5   0.1
    8   8.7   0.4
    9   6.7   3.5
   10   6.5   8.3
   11   6.3   2.6
   12   6.7   1.5
   13   0.2  16.6
   14   8.7   0.1
   15   7.5   1.3", header = T);
   ```
2. We define the Stan model, as a simple Gamma (Exponential) model with a log-link.

   ```
   model <- "
   data {
       int N;                                       // Number of observations
       int K;                                       // Number of parameters
       real y[N];                                   // Response
       matrix[N,K] X;                               // Model matrix
   }

   parameters {
       vector[K] beta;                              // Model parameters
   }

   transformed parameters {
       vector[N] lambda;
       lambda = exp(-X * beta);                     // log-link
   }

   model {
       // Priors
       beta[1] ~ cauchy(0, 10);
       for (i in 2:K)
           beta[i] ~ cauchy(0, 2.5);

       y ~ exponential(lambda);
   }
   "
   ```

   Here I assume (standard) weakly informative Cauchy priors on the beta model parameters.
3. We now fit the model to the data.

   ```
   library(rstan);
   options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores());
   rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE);

   X <- model.matrix(time ~ conc, data = df);
   model.stan <- stan(
       model_code = model,
       data = list(
           N = nrow(df),
           K = ncol(X),
           y = df$time,
           X = X),
       iter = 4000);
   ```
4. To compare point estimates, we also fit a Gamma GLM to the data using `glm`.

   ```
   model.glm <- glm(time ~ conc, data = df, family = Gamma(link = "log"));
   ```
5. The Stan model parameter estimates are

   ```
   summary(model.stan, "beta")$summary;
   #              mean     se_mean         sd       2.5%        25%        50%
   #beta[1]  2.9371457 0.016460000 0.62017934  1.8671652  2.5000356  2.8871936
   #beta[2] -0.3099799 0.002420744 0.09252423 -0.5045937 -0.3708111 -0.3046333
   #               75%      97.5%    n_eff     Rhat
   #beta[1]  3.3193334  4.3078478 1419.629 1.002440
   #beta[2] -0.2461567 -0.1412095 1460.876 1.002236
   ```

   The GLM model parameter estimates are

   ```
   summary(model.glm)$coef;
   #              Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
   #(Intercept)  2.8211487 0.54432115  5.182875 0.0001762685
   #conc        -0.3013355 0.08137986 -3.702827 0.0026556952
   ```

   We see good agreement between the Stan point estimates for the means and Gamma-GLM parameter estimates.
6. We plot parameter estimates from both the Stan and `glm` models.

   ```
   library(tidyverse);
   as.data.frame(summary(model.stan, "beta")$summary) %>%
       rownames_to_column("Parameter") %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = `50%`, y = Parameter)) +
       geom_point(size = 3) +
       geom_segment(aes(x = `2.5%`, xend = `97.5%`, yend = Parameter), size = 1) +
       geom_segment(aes(x = `25%`, xend = `75%`, yend = Parameter), size = 2) +
       labs(x = "Median (plus/minus 95% and 50% CIs)") +
       geom_point(
           data = data.frame(summary(model.glm)$coef, row.names = c("beta[1]", "beta[2]")) %>%
               rownames_to_column("Parameter"),
           aes(x = Estimate, y = Parameter),
           colour = "red", size = 4, shape = 1)
   ```

   [image]

   `glm` estimates are shown in red.

---

### Update (Fit Stan model using QR re-parametrisation)

1. Stan model with QR re-parametrisation.

   ```
   model.QR <- "
   data {
       int N;                                       // Number of observations
       int K;                                       // Number of parameters
       real y[N];                                   // Response
       matrix[N,K] X;                               // Model matrix
   }

   transformed data {
       matrix[N, K] Q;
       matrix[K, K] R;
       matrix[K, K] R_inverse;
       Q = qr_Q(X)[, 1:K];
       R = qr_R(X)[1:K, ];
       R_inverse = inverse(R);
   }

   parameters {
       vector[K] theta;
   }

   transformed parameters {
       vector[N] lambda;
       lambda = exp(-Q * theta);                     // log-link
   }

   model {
       y ~ exponential(lambda);
   }

   generated quantities {
       vector[K] beta;                              // Model parameters
       beta = R_inverse * theta;
   }
   "
   ```

   In the QR decomposition, we have `lambda = exp(- X * beta) = exp(- Q * R * beta) = exp(- Q * theta)`, where `theta = R * beta` and therefore `beta = R^-1 * theta`.

   Note that we do not specify any priors on theta; in Stan this defaults to flat (i.e. uniform) priors.
2. Fit Stan model to the data.

   ```
   library(rstan);
   options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores());
   rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE);

   X <- model.matrix(time ~ conc, data = df);
   model.stan.QR <- stan(
       model_code = model.QR,
       data = list(
           N = nrow(df),
           K = ncol(X),
           y = df$time,
           X = X),
       iter = 4000);
   ```
3. Parameter estimates

   ```
   summary(model.stan.QR, "beta")$summary;
   #              mean     se_mean         sd       2.5%        25%        50%
   #beta[1]  2.9637547 0.009129250 0.64383609  1.8396681  2.5174800  2.9194682
   #beta[2] -0.3134252 0.001321584 0.09477156 -0.5126905 -0.3740475 -0.3093937
   #               75%      97.5%    n_eff      Rhat
   #beta[1]  3.3498585  4.3593912 4973.710 0.9998545
   #beta[2] -0.2478029 -0.1395686 5142.408 1.0003236
   ```

   You can see that parameter estimates between the two Stan models (with and without QR re-parametrisation) agree very well.

   If you were to ask me whether QR re-parametrisation makes a (big/any) difference, I'd say "probably not in this case"; Andrew Gelman and others have often emphasised that using even very weakly informative priors will help with convergence and should be preferred over flat (uniform) priors; I would always try to use weakly informative priors on all parameters, and start with a model without QR re-parametrisation; if convergence is poor, I would then try to optimise my model in a next step.

Comment: Ahh, this is illuminating! Thanks again for the assistance. I have a couple of questions, I you don't mind. So we don't need to use the QR reparameterization for the Exponential GLM, as was done in the Poisson GLM example that I posted? Also, for the log-link, you have `lambda = exp(-X * beta)`. If I am not mistaken, this beta corresponds to the beta_1 in the model description. What about the beta_0?

Comment: @ThePointer (1) `beta[1]` corresponds to the offset (your beta_0); Stan use 1-based rather than 0-based indexing (with the nice side-effect of being more consistent with R). I've added a plot that shows a comparison of parameter estimates from both the Stan and `glm` models. (2) Concerning QR reparametrisation. I'm no expert on this, but from what I understand QR reparametrisation can help speed up the sampling process. It's an optimisation strategy that helps in particular if you have flat priors. [...]

Comment: [...] I have never used QR reparametrisation because most of the time I am able to provide weakly informative priors, and convergence of solutions are fine (you can check by looking at the `Rhat` values). So I'm sorry that I can't give a more comprehensive answer on that aspect. Perhaps somebody from the Rstan/Stan team can provide insight; I know that they monitor SO for Stan-related questions; or perhaps ask a separate question on the Stan Google forums.

Comment: @ThePointer I've added an example showing how to fit the Stan model using QR re-parametrisation; please take a look and let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: Wow!!! Your answer is absolutely superb! Thank you so much for taking the time to create such a detailed and illuminating answer. Your explanations are clear, and I think I understand everything now. So, using your outputs, the 95% credible intervals for `beta[1]` and `beta[2]` would just be the interval from the 2.5% quantile to the 97.5% quantile? And if I wanted to put informative priors on `beta[1]` and `beta[2]` in the QR reparametrisation, I would just put priors on `theta[1]` and `theta[2]`?

Comment: You're very welcome @ThePointer; I like these Stan/Rstan modelling questions, as (R)stan is a fantastic framework IMO. You're correct on the interpretation of the 95% credible interval. Concerning, priors, yes in the QR re-parametrisation model you could supply weakly informative priors (such as the Cauchy priors) on the theta parameters. But in that case, you might as well use the first model. From what I understand, QR re-parametrisation is an optimisation strategy that is suitable when solutions don't converge (which can happen when you have flat priors and/or `K` is large); [...]

Comment: [...] In your case, convergence is not really an issue even with flat priors in the first model. So the additional benefit of QR re-parametrisation seems small in this case. But it's still good to know how to implement it; I had never used QR re-parametrisation, so I've learned something new from your example;-)

Comment: Understood. Thanks again for the assistance. I'm a little embarrassed to ask so soon after you answered this question, but would you happen to have any experience with hierarchical modelling? I'm trying to convert a nonlinear growth model that I have previously implemented in Stan into a hierarchical model. Again, if it isn't too much trouble, I'd greatly appreciate it if you could please explain this implementation in a similar way as you did here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749414/developing-hierarchical-version-of-nonlinear-growth-curve-model-in-stan