# Developing hierarchical version of nonlinear growth curve model in Stan

Tags: r, statistics, stan, rstan

The following model is model 1 of Preece and Baines (1978, *Annals of Human Biology*), and is used to describe human growth.

[image]

My Stan code for this model is as follows:

````
```{stan output.var="test"}
 data {
  int<lower=1> n;
  ordered[n] t; // age
  ordered[n] y; // height of human
 }
 
 parameters {
  positive_ordered[2] h;
  real<lower=0, upper=t[n-1]>theta;
  positive_ordered[2] s; 
  real<lower=0>sigma;
 }
 
 model {
  h[1] ~ uniform(0, y[n]);
  h[2] ~ normal(180, 20);
  sigma ~ student_t(2, 0, 1);
  s[1] ~ normal(5, 5);
  s[2] ~ normal(5, 5);
  theta ~ normal(10, 5);
  
  y ~ normal(h[2] - (2*(h[2] - h[1]) * inv(exp(s[1]*(t - theta)) + exp(s[2]*(t - theta)))), sigma);
 }
```
````

I now want to create a hierarchical version of this model, with parameters modelled either identical across boys (such as the measurement variability `sigma`) or in a hierarchical version (such as h_1, the adult height).

[image]

As for the parameters `sigma` and `theta`, I want to maintain these priors as identical across boys as `sigma ~ student_t(2, 0, 1);` and `theta ~ normal(10, 5);`.

Unfortunately, I have almost no experience in implementing hierarchical modelling, and I have struggled in my attempts at doing any hierarchical examples beyond the simple binomial hierarchical models in Bayesian textbooks (see chapter 12, pages 358-359 of *Statistical Rethinking* by Richard McElreath). I do, however, understand the theory behind hierarchical modelling, as written in chapter 5 of *Bayesian Data Analysis* by Andrew Gelman and chapter 12 of *Statistical Rethinking* by Richard McElreath.

I am keen to discover how this type of hierarchical model would be implemented in Stan. Ideally, I am seeking explanations alongside the code, so that I may learn how to implement these types of hierarchical model examples independently in the future.

A sample of my data is as follows:

```
    age boy01 boy02 boy03 boy04 boy05 boy06 boy07 boy08 boy09 boy10 boy11 boy12 boy13 boy14 boy15 boy16 boy17 boy18
 1  1     81.3  76.2  76.8  74.1  74.2  76.8  72.4  73.8  75.4  78.8  76.9  81.6  78    76.4  76.4  76.2  75    79.7
 2  1.25  84.2  80.4  79.8  78.4  76.3  79.1  76    78.7  81    83.3  79.9  83.7  81.8  79.4  81.2  79.2  78.4  81.3
 3  1.5   86.4  83.2  82.6  82.6  78.3  81.1  79.4  83    84.9  87    84.1  86.3  85    83.4  86    82.3  82    83.3
 4  1.75  88.9  85.4  84.7  85.4  80.3  84.4  82    85.8  87.9  89.6  88.5  88.8  86.4  87.6  89.2  85.4  84    86.5
 5  2     91.4  87.6  86.7  88.1  82.2  87.4  84.2  88.4  90    91.4  90.6  92.2  87.1  91.4  92.2  88.4  85.9  88.9
 6  3    101.   97    94.2  98.6  89.4  94    93.2  97.3  97.3 100.   96.6  99.3  96.2 101.  101.  101    95.6  99.4
 7  4    110.  105.  100.  104.   96.9 102.  102.  107.  103.  111   105.  106.  104   106.  110.  107.  102.  104. 
 8  5    116.  112.  107.  111   104.  109.  109   113.  108.  118.  112   113.  111   113.  117.  115.  109.  112. 
 9  6    122.  119.  112.  116.  111.  116.  117.  119.  114.  126.  119.  120.  117.  120.  122.  121.  118.  119  
10  7    130   125   119.  123.  116.  122.  123.  126.  120.  131.  125.  127.  124.  129.  130.  128   125.  128
```

I acknowledge the lack of precision in the decimal places. The data is in the form of a tibble table, which doesn't seem to respond to R's usual commands for greater precision. For the sake of consistency, it might be better to simply ignore all of the rows after row 5, since rows 1 - 5 display the full precision that is present in the original data.

In the full data, the ages are

```
> Children$age
 [1]  1.00  1.25  1.50  1.75  2.00  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.00  7.00  8.00  8.50  9.00  9.50 10.00 10.50 11.00 11.50 12.00 12.50
[21] 13.00 13.50 14.00 14.50 15.00 15.50 16.00 16.50 17.00 17.50 18.00
```

And there are 39 boys, listed in the same wide-data format as the above sample.

Comment: Detailed questions about specific R packages such as Stan are probably best asked on the r-help mailing list. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the first growth model (let's ignore the hierarchical extension for the moment): (1) `h1` corresponds to the *"adult height of the individual"*; so `h_1` should just be `max(y)`, shouldn't it? In which case, it's not really a parameter of the model. Is that correct? (2) I see difficulties in estimating `s_0` and `s_1`: As is stated, both parameters are non-distinguishable; in other words, you really only need one of them. In a model with regularising priors on `s_0`/`s_1` (which you will need), I would imagine one of the `s`s simply being driven to zero. Do you agree?

Comment: On a more general note: I a first step, I would first construct and test a completely pooled (non-hierarchical) Stan model based on the simple growth model. You will get a feeling for convergence and posterior densities of the parameters involved. Then from there, turn your model in a hierarchical model with partial-pooling. This sounds like an interesting modelling problem, but I'm still unclear on the simple growth model and its parameters (see my previous comment).

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks for taking the time to respond again. My understanding of the Preece and Baines growth model is that `h[1]` is intended to be modelled as a parameter. Since I'm a novice with regards to Bayesian inference, I defaulted to this stance. With regards to `s_0`/`s_1`, I also remember seeing that these were both modelled as parameters with the constraints 0 < `s_0` < `s_1` imposed. As to whether one of the `s`s is driven to zero, that could be the case, but I modelled the values in this way because that seemed like what was intended.

Comment: @ThePointer Hi again;-) Regarding `s_0`/`s_1`: Yes I understand the idea of ordering them to make them distinguishable, but take a look at the results from a simple growth model in my answer below. You can see how `s_0` and `s_1` cannot be estimated simultaneously. Ordering them won't help with that.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Ahh, I just finished reading it. Indeed, It seems that you are correct. Well, in that case, we can do what is necessary to either of the `s_0` or `s_1` in order for the model itself to fit. My interest is more-so in the hierarchical version of the non-linear growth model and how such a hierarchical model would be implemented in Stan, so we can do what it necessary to the `s_0`/`s_1` values. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: As a start let's fit a (non-hierarchical) non-linear growth model using Stan.

1. We read in the sample data.

   ```
   library(tidyverse);
   df <- read.table(text = "
   age boy01 boy02 boy03 boy04 boy05 boy06 boy07 boy08 boy09 boy10 boy11 boy12 boy13 boy14 boy15 boy16 boy17 boy18
   1  1     81.3  76.2  76.8  74.1  74.2  76.8  72.4  73.8  75.4  78.8  76.9  81.6  78    76.4  76.4  76.2  75    79.7
   2  1.25  84.2  80.4  79.8  78.4  76.3  79.1  76    78.7  81    83.3  79.9  83.7  81.8  79.4  81.2  79.2  78.4  81.3
   3  1.5   86.4  83.2  82.6  82.6  78.3  81.1  79.4  83    84.9  87    84.1  86.3  85    83.4  86    82.3  82    83.3
   4  1.75  88.9  85.4  84.7  85.4  80.3  84.4  82    85.8  87.9  89.6  88.5  88.8  86.4  87.6  89.2  85.4  84    86.5
   5  2     91.4  87.6  86.7  88.1  82.2  87.4  84.2  88.4  90    91.4  90.6  92.2  87.1  91.4  92.2  88.4  85.9  88.9
   6  3    101.   97    94.2  98.6  89.4  94    93.2  97.3  97.3 100.   96.6  99.3  96.2 101.  101.  101    95.6  99.4
   7  4    110.  105.  100.  104.   96.9 102.  102.  107.  103.  111   105.  106.  104   106.  110.  107.  102.  104.
   8  5    116.  112.  107.  111   104.  109.  109   113.  108.  118.  112   113.  111   113.  117.  115.  109.  112.
   9  6    122.  119.  112.  116.  111.  116.  117.  119.  114.  126.  119.  120.  117.  120.  122.  121.  118.  119
   10  7    130   125   119.  123.  116.  122.  123.  126.  120.  131.  125.  127.  124.  129.  130.  128   125.  128", header = T, row.names = 1);
   df <- df %>%
       gather(boy, height, -age);
   ```
2. We define the Stan model.

   ```
   model <- "
   data {
       int N;                                       // Number of observations
       real y[N];                                   // Height
       real t[N];                                   // Time
   }

   parameters {
       real<lower=0,upper=1> s[2];
       real h_theta;
       real theta;
       real sigma;
   }

   transformed parameters {
       vector[N] mu;
       real h1;
       h1 = max(y);
       for (i in 1:N)
           mu[i] = h1 - 2 * (h1 - h_theta) / (exp(s[1] * (t[i] - theta)) + (exp(s[2] * (t[i] - theta))));
   }

   model {
       // Priors
       s ~ cauchy(0, 2.5);

       y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
   }
   "
   ```

   Here we consider weakly informative (regularising) priors on `s[1]` and `s[2]`.
3. Fit the model to the data.

   ```
   library(rstan);
   options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores());
   rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE);    
   model <- stan(
       model_code = model,
       data = list(
           N = nrow(df),
           y = df$height,
           t = df$age),
       iter = 4000);
   ```
4. Summary of the 6 model parameters:

   ```
   summary(model, pars = c("h1", "h_theta", "theta", "s", "sigma"))$summary 
   #               mean     se_mean        sd        2.5%         25%         50%
   #h1      131.0000000 0.000000000 0.0000000 131.0000000 131.0000000 131.0000000
   #h_theta 121.6874553 0.118527828 2.7554944 115.4316738 121.1654809 122.2134014
   #theta     6.5895553 0.019738319 0.5143429   5.4232740   6.4053479   6.6469534
   #s[1]      0.7170836 0.214402086 0.3124318   0.1748077   0.3843143   0.8765256
   #s[2]      0.3691174 0.212062373 0.3035039   0.1519308   0.1930381   0.2066811
   #sigma     3.1524819 0.003510676 0.1739904   2.8400096   3.0331962   3.1411533
   #                75%       97.5%       n_eff     Rhat
   #h1      131.0000000 131.0000000 8000.000000      NaN
   #h_theta 123.0556379 124.3928800  540.453594 1.002660
   #theta     6.8790801   7.3376348  679.024115 1.002296
   #s[1]      0.9516115   0.9955989    2.123501 3.866466
   #s[2]      0.2954409   0.9852540    2.048336 6.072550
   #sigma     3.2635849   3.5204101 2456.231113 1.001078
   ```

   So what does this mean? From the `Rhat` values for `s[1]` and `s[2]` you can see that there are issues with convergence for these two parameters. This is due to the fact that `s[1]` and `s[2]` are indistinguishable: they cannot be estimated both at the same time. A stronger regularising prior on `s[1]` and `s[2]` would probably drive one of the `s` parameters to zero.

I'm not sure I understand the point of `s[1]` and `s[2]`. From a statistical modelling point of view, you cannot obtain estimates for both parameters in the simple non-linear growth model that we're considering.

---

### Update

As promised here is an update. This is turning into quite a long post, I've tried to make things as clear as possible by adding additional explanations.

#### Preliminary comments

1. Using `positive_ordered` as data type for `s` makes a significant difference in terms of convergence of solutions. It's not clear to me why that is the case, nor do I know how Stan implements `positive_ordered`, but it works.
2. In this hierarchical approach, we partially pool height data across all boys by considering `h1 ~ normal(mu_h1, sigma_h1)`, with priors on the hyperparameters `mu_h1 ~ normal(max(y), 10)` and a half-Cauchy prior on `sigma_h1 ~ cauchy(0, 10)` (it's half-Cauchy because `sigma` is declared as `real<lower=0>`).
3. To be honest, I am unsure about the interpretation (and interpretability) of some of the parameters. Estimates for `h_1` and `h_theta` are very similar, and in some way cancel each other out. I would imagine that this creates some convergence issues when fitting the model, but as you can see further down, `Rhat` values seem ok. Still, as I don't know enough about the model, data and its context, I remain somewhat skeptical as to the interpretability of those parameters. Extending the model by turning some of the other parameters into group-level parameters is straightforward from a statistical modelling point of view; however I imagine that difficulties will arise from the indistinguishability and lack of interpretability.

All these points aside, this should give you a practical example of how to implement a hierarchical model.

#### The Stan model

```
model_code <- "
data {
    int N;                                       // Number of observations
    int J;                                       // Number of boys
    int<lower=1,upper=J> boy[N];                 // Boy of observation
    real y[N];                                   // Height
    real t[N];                                   // Time
}

parameters {
    real<lower=0> h1[J];
    real<lower=0> h_theta;
    real<lower=0> theta;
    positive_ordered[2] s;
    real<lower=0> sigma;

    // Hyperparameters
    real<lower=0> mu_h1;
    real<lower=0> sigma_h1;
}

transformed parameters {
    vector[N] mu;

    for (i in 1:N)
        mu[i] = h1[boy[i]] - 2 * (h1[boy[i]] - h_theta) / (exp(s[1] * (t[i] - theta)) + (exp(s[2] * (t[i] - theta))));
}

model {
    h1 ~ normal(mu_h1, sigma_h1);          // Partially pool h1 parameters across boys

    mu_h1 ~ normal(max(y), 10);            // Prior on h1 hyperparameter mu
    sigma_h1 ~ cauchy(0, 10);              // Half-Cauchy prior on h1 hyperparameter sigma
    h_theta ~ normal(max(y), 2);           // Prior on h_theta
    theta ~ normal(max(t), 2);             // Prior on theta
    s ~ cauchy(0, 1);                      // Half-Cauchy priors on s[1] and s[2]

    y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
"
```

To summarise: We pool height data from all boys to improve estimates at the group (i.e. boy) level, by modelling the adult height parameter as `h1 ~ normal(mu_h1, sigma_h1)`, where the hyperparameters `mu_h1` and `sigma_h1` characterise the normal distribution of adult height values across all boys. We choose weakly informative priors on the hyperparameters, and choose weakly informative priors on all remaining parameters similar to the first complete-pooling example.

#### Fit the model

```
# Fit model
fit <- stan(
    model_code = model_code,
    data = list(
        N = nrow(df),
        J = length(unique(df$boy)),
        boy = df$boy,
        y = df$height,
        t = df$age),
    iter = 4000)
```

#### Extract summary

We extract parameter estimates for all parameters; note that we now have as many `h1` parameters as there are groups (i.e. boys).

```
# Get summary
summary(fit, pars = c("h1", "h_theta", "theta", "s", "sigma"))$summary
#               mean      se_mean         sd        2.5%         25%        50%
#h1[1]   142.9406153 0.1046670943 2.41580757 138.4272280 141.2858391 142.909765
#h1[2]   143.7054020 0.1070466445 2.46570025 139.1301456 142.0233342 143.652657
#h1[3]   144.0352331 0.1086953809 2.50145442 139.3982034 142.3131167 143.971473
#h1[4]   143.8589955 0.1075753575 2.48015745 139.2689731 142.1666685 143.830347
#h1[5]   144.7359976 0.1109871908 2.55284812 140.0529359 142.9917503 144.660586
#h1[6]   143.9844938 0.1082691127 2.49497990 139.3378948 142.2919990 143.926931
#h1[7]   144.3857221 0.1092604239 2.51645359 139.7349112 142.6665955 144.314645
#h1[8]   143.7469630 0.1070594855 2.46860328 139.1748700 142.0660983 143.697302
#h1[9]   143.6841113 0.1072208284 2.47391295 139.0885987 141.9839040 143.644357
#h1[10]  142.9518072 0.1041206784 2.40729732 138.4289207 141.3114204 142.918407
#h1[11]  143.5352502 0.1064173663 2.45712021 138.9607665 141.8547610 143.483157
#h1[12]  143.0941582 0.1050061258 2.42894673 138.5579378 141.4295430 143.055576
#h1[13]  143.6194965 0.1068494690 2.46574352 138.9426195 141.9412820 143.577920
#h1[14]  143.4477182 0.1060254849 2.44776536 138.9142081 141.7708660 143.392231
#h1[15]  143.1415683 0.1049131998 2.42575487 138.6246642 141.5014391 143.102219
#h1[16]  143.5686919 0.1063594201 2.45328456 139.0064573 141.8962853 143.510276
#h1[17]  144.0170715 0.1080567189 2.49269747 139.4162885 142.3138300 143.965127
#h1[18]  143.4740997 0.1064867748 2.45545200 138.8768051 141.7989566 143.426211
#h_theta 134.3394366 0.0718785944 1.72084291 130.9919889 133.2348411 134.367152
#theta     8.2214374 0.0132434918 0.45236221   7.4609612   7.9127800   8.164685
#s[1]      0.1772044 0.0004923951 0.01165119   0.1547003   0.1705841   0.177522
#s[2]      1.6933846 0.0322953612 1.18334358   0.6516669   1.1630900   1.463148
#sigma     2.2601677 0.0034146522 0.13271459   2.0138514   2.1657260   2.256678
#                75%       97.5%     n_eff     Rhat
#h1[1]   144.4795105 147.8847202  532.7265 1.008214
#h1[2]   145.2395543 148.8419618  530.5599 1.008187
#h1[3]   145.6064981 149.2080965  529.6183 1.008087
#h1[4]   145.4202919 149.0105666  531.5363 1.008046
#h1[5]   146.3200407 150.0701757  529.0592 1.008189
#h1[6]   145.5551778 149.1365279  531.0372 1.008109
#h1[7]   145.9594956 149.5996605  530.4593 1.008271
#h1[8]   145.3032680 148.8695637  531.6824 1.008226
#h1[9]   145.2401743 148.7674840  532.3662 1.008023
#h1[10]  144.4811712 147.9218834  534.5465 1.007937
#h1[11]  145.1153635 148.5968945  533.1235 1.007988
#h1[12]  144.6479561 148.0546831  535.0652 1.008115
#h1[13]  145.1660639 148.6562172  532.5386 1.008138
#h1[14]  144.9975197 148.5273804  532.9900 1.008067
#h1[15]  144.6733010 148.1130207  534.6057 1.008128
#h1[16]  145.1163764 148.6027096  532.0396 1.008036
#h1[17]  145.5578107 149.2014363  532.1519 1.008052
#h1[18]  145.0249329 148.4886949  531.7060 1.008055
#h_theta 135.4870338 137.6753254  573.1698 1.006818
#theta     8.4812339   9.2516700 1166.7226 1.002306
#s[1]      0.1841457   0.1988365  559.9036 1.005333
#s[2]      1.8673249   4.1143099 1342.5839 1.001562
#sigma     2.3470429   2.5374239 1510.5824 1.001219
```

#### Visualise adult height estimates

Finally we plot adult height estimates `h_1` for all boys, including 50% and 97% confidence intervals.

```
# Plot h1 values
summary(fit, pars = c("h1"))$summary %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rownames_to_column("Variable") %>%
    mutate(
        Variable = gsub("(h1\\[|\\])", "", Variable),
        Variable = df$key[match(Variable, df$boy)]) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = `50%`, y = Variable)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = `2.5%`, xend = `97.5%`, yend = Variable), size = 1) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = `25%`, xend = `75%`, yend = Variable), size = 2) +
    labs(x = "Median (plus/minus 95% and 50% CIs)", y = "h1")
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about this further throughout the day. Any chance you could demonstrate the hierarchical version of the non-linear growth model with all of the terms (including `h[1]`, `s_0`, and `s_1`) present in the form mentioned? As you demonstrated, the output would show that the values `s_0` and `s_1` don't converge. In which case, what would we do in such a situation? Would we have to change the hierarchical model in some way? [...]

Comment: [...] As I said, I'm mostly interested in the Stan implementation of the hierarchical model from an educational standpoint, so the fact that `s_0` and `s_1` don't converge isn't of primary interest to me, since I'm not really interested in the posterior values themselves.

Comment: @ThePointer The problem is not only the `s_0`/`s_1` indistinguishability. If we let `h1` be a free model parameter, the model also struggles to simultaneously obtain estimates for the `h_1` and  `h_theta` parameters, even with (weakly) regularising priors. If we fix `h_1 = max(y)`, then solutions converge but I'm not sure that is what you're after. I've played around with various models+priors a fair bit, and so far haven't had much luck fitting a robust non-linear growth model as specified in your post to the sample data. [...]

Comment: [...] Could you elaborate on the interpretation of the `h_1` and `h_theta` parameters? According to the reference you give, `h_1` corresponds to the adult height; can we always assume this to be `max(y)` for every boy? What is the interpretation of `h_theta`? You can see from my initial Stan results, that `h_theta` and `h_1` are quite close. That's another reason for the overall poor convergence of solutions of the model.

Comment: Thanks again for the assistance. I've been playing around with the parameters, but I get the same values as those in your posted output. Unfortunately, this is all of the information I have regarding model 1 of Preece and Baines. Any chance you could please post the hierarchical code with the aforementioned `s_0`, `s_1`, and `h[1]`, so that I can play around with the hierarchical version? Even if the `s_0`, `s_1`, and `h_1` hierarchical parameters do not converge, I can still learn from the hierarchical structure of the code and play around with the model to see what happens from there. [...]

Comment: [..] I've also been playing around with other hierarchical non-linear models to try to gain familiarity with hierarchical non-linear model implementation, so I can try to compare the two hierarchical models and play around with them.

Comment: @ThePointer I'll post an update tomorrow. Need to collect my results and it's getting late here;-)

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks again for taking the time to clarify these things. Learning Stan and Bayesian inference is difficult when all you have access to are a couple of textbooks and few internet resources. :(

Comment: @ThePointer I've added an update where I show how to fit a simple hierarchical model with one group-level parameter (the adult height `h_1`). Please take a look.

Comment: I wanted to to thank you again for taking the time to clarify things. Thanks to your kindness and generosity, I was able to better understand hierarchical modelling. I managed to partially pool the parameters I mentioned in my main post across boys, but, unfortunately, even the simplest hierarchical model (that with only `h1` partially pooled across boys) was not converging when used with the full data set (although, weirdly enough, it converges with the partial data set I provided here!). This is, of course, as you said. [...]

Comment: Anyway, I guess I'll have to leave this specific model as is. There are, of course, many other non-linear models that one can model hierarchically, so there's plenty to practice with if necessary. Either way, this was a hugely enlightening educational experience for me. Thank you again!

Comment: You're very welcome @ThePointer! Good luck with your further research. If you'd like to learn more about hierarchical models in Stan, I can recommend two books that help(ed) me a lot: Statistical Rethinking by Richard McElreath is a fantastic modern (introductory) book on statistical modelling (using Stan/RStan); Data Analysis Using Regression & Multilevel/Hierarchical Model by Gelman & Hill is one of the most comprehensive textbook in that area that I came across, with many practical examples; [...]

Comment: [...] Andrew Gelman is one of the Stan devs, and I know that he and Jennifer Hill are planning to release a (two volume) revised edition of the book soon, where examples have been translated from Bugs to RStan.